# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group: Flutter.h file not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, apple-m1

I have a flutter app and I recently migrated to a macbook M1, and I started getting this error. I already tried the following steps:

> Remove iOS folder and create a new one

> `pod deintegrate` -> `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub cache repair` -> `pod install` -> `sudo gem install cocoa-pods`

> `rm Flutter/Flutter.podspec`, `rm Podfile.lock`

The output:

```
fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import "Flutter/Flutter.h"
```

My flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale pt-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution?